# I don't even know where to start with making a buffer to hold previous entries on search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, buffer

Im trying to make an electron/react application with a search bar form that users can use upstroke to replace an entry with a previous entry. Similarly to how terminals are. My only problem is I have no idea where to even start with that. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**three states and one input field**

We can make a simple `Prompt` like the one pictured below -

| Prompt preview |
| --- |
| [image: app preview] |

We'll start by defining the states for `history`, `recall`, and `command`. We will update the command whenever the user types in the `input` field, also making sure to clear the `recall` state, if any -

```js
function Prompt() {
  const [history, setHistory] = React.useState([]) // history of all commands
  const [recall, setRecall] = React.useState(0) // recall state
  const [command, setCommand] = React.useState("") // current command
  
  const onChange = event => {
    setCommand(event.target.value)
    setRecall(0)
  }

  return <div>
    {"> "}<input onChange={onChange} value={command} />
  </div>
}
```

**detect special key presses**

Next we attach listeners for the Up, Down, and Enter key presses in an `onKeyDown` event listener. To keep the `recall` state in bounds, we use `Math.min` and `Math.max`. And `event.preventDefault` is used to prevent the default behaviour of the browser responding to these specific key presses -

```js
function Prompt() {
  // ...

  const onKeyDown = event => {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 38: // UP press
        event.preventDefault()
        setRecall(Math.max(-history.length, recall - 1))
        break
      case 40: // DOWN press
        event.preventDefault()
        setRecall(Math.min(0, recall + 1))
        break
      case 13: // ENTER press
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log("execute(", command, ")")
        setHistory([...history, command])
        setCommand("")
        setRecall(0)
        break
    }
  }

  return <div>
    {"> "}<input onKeyDown={onKeyDown} onChange={onChange} value={command} />
  </div>
}
```

**recall command effect**

Finally, add an effect to update the `command` using the `recall` state whenever the `recall` state changes. A recall of `-1` means recall the last command, and `-2` is the second last command, and so on. If it is `0` skip this recall -

```js
function Prompt() {
  // ...

  React.useEffect(_ => {
    if (recall == 0) return
    setCommand(history[history.length + recall])
  }, [recall])

  return <div>
    {"> "}<input onKeyDown={onKeyDown} onChange={onChange} value={command} />
  </div>
}
```

**demo**

<kbd>Run</kbd> the code below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
function Prompt() {
  const [history, setHistory] = React.useState([])
  const [recall, setRecall] = React.useState(0)
  const [command, setCommand] = React.useState("")
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    if (recall == 0) return
    setCommand(history[history.length + recall])
  }, [recall])
  const onKeyDown = event => {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 38: // UP press
        event.preventDefault()
        setRecall(Math.max(-history.length, recall - 1))
        break
      case 40: // DOWN press
        event.preventDefault()
        setRecall(Math.min(0, recall + 1))
        break
      case 13: // ENTER press
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log("execute(", command, ")")
        setHistory([...history, command])
        setCommand("")
        setRecall(0)
        break
    }
  }
  const onChange = event => {
    setCommand(event.target.value)
    setRecall(0)
  }
  return <div>
    {"> "}<input onKeyDown={onKeyDown} onChange={onChange} value={command} />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Prompt />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**restore previous session**

If you wish to save the history in localStorage or something, you could add an `initHistory` property to `Prompt`, allowing us to recall a previous session -

```js
function Prompt({ initHistory = [] }) {
  const [history, setHistory] = React.useState(initHistory)
  // ...
}
```

Then you can preload the Prompt's history by passing it as an property value -

```js
<Prompt initHistory={[ ... ]} />
```

Comment: If you have any questions, let me know where you're getting stuck and I'm happy to help ^^